# Can you edit all columns in a table using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, field

Using phpMyAdmin: can one alter a table's schema by inserting new columns, as one would using spreadsheet software?   Like when one creates a new table.

[image]

Comment: hope i didnt edit too much @Jarvis.  just say the word and i'll undo the proposèd edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the **Structure** tab you'll be able to affect the columns or add in new ones.

#### To edit existing columns

- Check the box on the left of the columns
- Click the pencil icon below the structure display.

The next screen will allow you to adjust the column properties of those selected.

#### To add in new columns

Look below the table structure display

- Enter however many new columns, and where in the table they'll go
- Click **Go**.

The next screen will allow you to enter the properties for each of the new columns for the table.

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Answer (score 0):

If you `select all` at the bottom of the screen below the table,then click change, you can change them all like you did when first creating the table.

[image: Like so.]